# Any tips / advice on debugging a Unity3d linux headless build?

Tags: c#, linux, debugging, unity-game-engine

Update ----- It was a hell of a pain in the ass, but I was finally able to get a proper working log. I had to install VirtualBox, get that all set up and going, then I tried first to install just Ubuntu server like I was using on my VPS but of course it came up with the same thing, so I got the desktop version, build the game and all the separate server components as GUI instances so I could enable debugging build, got it all shared and what not through VirtualBox, then got a test copy of my DB setup and imported in there. After a few hours all was said and done and I was able to finally fire it up and *finally* got a decent log out of it.

I am having some issues with my build. Everything of course works fine in the editor but when I build for linux and fire it up on my vps I am getting errors but unfortunately they are just not specific enough for me to really be able to do anything about it. I think it might have something to do with threading and accessing my DB, unfortunately its just coming back with with the following which is not that helpful.

```
(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
at Framework.Server.Game.LoadWorld () [0x00010] in <b5f83ac7652b49ea9b6c5870ec6e0fad>:0
(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
```

LoadWorld() doesn't really help much as it is a pretty darn meaty function.
I have a try catch in there and am trying to use as seen below, but it didn't give me much more :

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e.Message);
    Debug.Log(e.StackTrace);
    throw;
}

(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
at Framework.Server.Game.LoadWorld () [0x00248] in <b5f83ac7652b49ea9b6c5870ec6e0fad>:0
at Framework.Server.Game..ctor (Framework.Server.Game.IWorldServer server,Framework.Server.Config.GameConfig gameConfiguration, 
Framework.Server.Game.WorldInfo worldInfo) [0x000a7] in <b5f83ac7652b49ea9b6c5870ec6e0fad>:0
```

but it's still not really giving me anything. I have it logging both to a file (log4net) and to the actual terminal thought its not much difference in the log. Without any line numbers or anything its kind of leaving me hanging.

Does anyone have any info or tips on things I can use (assets, libraries, applications on the server) to help somehow give some more information?

Thanks!